# Filter multiple value with getServerSideProps from query result

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context, getserversideprops

How to have filtered multiple results in a `getServerSideProps`. I send all my results the query parameter:

```
const filtersUsers = (changedValues, allValues) => {
    router.push({
        query : { ...allValues },
    })
}
```

In my URL I get this result when I start to filter: http://127.0.0.1:8082/users?lastname=lastnameFilter&firstname=firstnameFilter&email=&city=&zipcode=

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
const res = await fetch(`http://my-project-api:8081/api/users/`)
console.log(res)
const users = await res.json()

if (!users) {
  return {
    notFound: true,
  }
}

return {
  props: {users},
}
```

}

How can I apply the query only to items that have a filled in field and update my url with those filled out fields, and how to use the `context.query` so that it automatically knows which field to look for in my table?

I have create an API factory and I can do that.

```
await api.getUsers(params)
```

Result: **Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/users/?lastname=lastnameTest&firstname=firstnameTest**

And in param I have all fields for filters. I search how I can do this with **getServerSideProps**

Comment: Not entirely clear what you're asking, do you need to access the query string in `getServerSideProps`? You can do that using `context.query`.

Comment: I'm looking to filter with multiple filter fields from getServerSideProps